# How to use D3 selectAll with multiple class names

Tags: svg, d3.js, selectall

I'm experimenting with using multiple class names for SVG elements so that (hopefully) I could select a subset of them using selectAll and "parts" of the class name.  Unfortunately nothing I've tried works and I haven't found an example online.  The code below demonstrates what I'm trying to do with a simple example of four circles.  Two circles have class name "mYc 101" and two circles have class name "mYc 202".  selectAll(".mYc") gives all four circles.  What if I want only the circles with class name "mYc 101"?  Can this be done?  How?  Thanks times infinity!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<div id="my_div"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var m_div = d3.select("#my_div");
    var m_svg = m_div.append("svg");

    var g = m_svg.append("g");

    g.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "mYc 101")
        .attr("cx", 100)
        .attr("cy", 100)
        .attr("r", 50) 
        .attr("style", "stroke: green; stroke-width: 8; fill: #000000");

    g.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "mYc 101")
        .attr("cx", 300)
        .attr("cy", 100)
        .attr("r", 50) 
        .attr("style", "stroke: green; stroke-width: 8; fill: #000000");

    g.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "mYc 202")
        .attr("cx", 100)
        .attr("cy", 300)
        .attr("r", 50) 
        .attr("style", "stroke: blue; stroke-width: 8; fill: #000000");

    g.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "mYc 202")
        .attr("cx", 300)
        .attr("cy", 300)
        .attr("r", 50) 
        .attr("style", "stroke: blue; stroke-width: 8; fill: #000000");

    // This selects all four circles
    var list = d3.selectAll(".mYc");

    // But if I want to select only class "mYc 101", none of these work.
    // In fact they all give an error.
    // var list1 = d3.selectAll(".mYc 101");
    // var list1 = d3.selectAll(".mYc .101");
    // var list1 = d3.selectAll(".mYc.101");
    // var list1 = d3.selectAll(".mYc,.101");
    // var list1 = d3.selectAll(".101");

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The most D3 way to do this would be to chain the selectors using the `filter` method:

```
var list1 = d3.selectAll(".mYc").filter(".101");
```

This won't work though because class names cannot start with a number. So you have to rename to something like "a101" and then you can do

```
var list1 = d3.selectAll(".mYc").filter(".a101");
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pW4Te/2/).

Comment: Thanks so much Lars!!  The key was the fact that class names cannot start with a number.  Bill

Answer (score 39):

Another way I have found to do this is to select both classes at the same time as a single string, for example:

```
var list1 = d3.selectAll(".mYc.a101")
```

It won't work if you add in a space in between, or add a comma in between (which selects things that have either class instead).

Comment: Lars' answer is fuller, but this is the one that helped me understand.

Comment: furthermore, you can use `var list1 = d3.selectAll("circle.mYc.a101")`